# What is the meaning of this sentence: "how many Xs exist as of the last block?"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I want to know the exact meaning of "how many Xs exist as of the last block?"

Does it mean "how many Xs exist in the last block?"

Or does it mean "how many Xs exist in all blocks including the last block?"

Comment: I think we need to know what X is. Another possibility is "in all blocks up to the last block". I don't think your first sentence is the meaning, but "up to the last block" or "up to and including the last block" are both possibilities, and what X is may well have a bearing on which to plump for.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Each block might have one or multiple Xs. The original sentence is:
How many UTXOs exist as of the last block of the data set?

Comment: So we're talking Bitcoin blockchains.

Comment: Exactly! I was reading a homework on Bitcoin (from Stanford university).

Comment: The prepositional phrase 'as of' indicates that the sentence means "how many Xs exist in all blocks including the last block", but I can't explain why at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

The prepositional phrase 'as of' indicates that the sentence means "how many Xs exist in all blocks including the last block."

---

#### Usual meaning for the prepositional phrase 'as of'

The prepositional phrase 'as of' traditionally refers to time. For example, the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11307?redirectedFrom=as%20of#eid194115997) gives these two definitions:

> (a) as things stood on (a date); (*orig. U.S.*) (in formal dating)
>   reckoning from; from, after.
>
> (b) *orig. U.S.* as of now:  (a) at the present time;  (b) from this
>   moment, from now.

And a blog post titled, [Common Mistakes in Business English](https://blog.harwardcommunications.com/2012/04/02/as-of/), notes:

> Although ["as of"] is very common in business writing it can create
>   ambiguity if used incorrectly. Ambiguity is caused by the fact that
>   “as of” has three different meanings: on, since or from, depending on
>   the context.
>
> Have a look at these sentences:
>
> The contract enters into force as of 1 January 2013. = on
>
> The contract has been effective as of 1 August 2011. = since
>
> The contract is effective as of 1 January 2013. = from

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20of) indicates:

> :  on, at, from —used to indicate a time or date at which something
>   begins or ends takes effect; *as of July 1*

#### Time is a sequence

The sentence you presented, "how many Xs exist as of the last block?" does not refer to time, but rather to a quantity within a sequence, which if you think about it is not far afield from a quantity of time within a sequence of seconds (or minutes or hours).

Thus, your sentence is analogous to "As of 23:00 how many hours have passed since he went missing?" If the missing person was last seen at 12:00, then 11 hours have passed. This example uses 'as of' in the sense of "as of now", "at this moment", "at".

Note that in this example, the questioner does *not* want to know "How much time is there at the present moment?" (analogous to "how many Xs exist in the last block?"). And he or she also does *not* want to know "How much time has passed, up until the previous hour" (analogous to "in all blocks up to the last block"). He or she wants to know "How much time has passed up to and including the present moment?" (analogous to "how many Xs exist in all blocks including the last block").